# Why did 320x240 become the famous Mode X, and not 400x300?

Tags: graphics-programming

[Mode X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_X) was hack invented during the good old days of DOS gaming, offering 320x240 resolution, 256 colors, square pixels, and page flipping.

VGA adapters had 256 KB of memory.

320 * 240 = 76800 bytes
262144 / 76800 = 3.413 pages

So you have lots of memory left over when you do page flipping with two pages (equivalent of double buffering).

400 * 300 = 120000 bytes
262144 / 120000 = 2.18453 pages

You get all the benefits of Mode X, but more resolution. So what is the reason 400x300 resolution didn't become the standard for DOS games? What were its drawbacks?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_13h

Comment: This was slightly before my time, but could it be one reason that the latter case left barely any VRAM left for storing sprites in VRAM? Or maybe a 3rd page was commonly used for storing all the static parts of the game so the animated sprites could be blitted on top every frame without having to redraw the background?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about historical industry trivia.

Comment: The original VGA monitors only supported a limited range of timings, limiting them to video modes using either 480, 400, or 350 horizontal lines when using standard VGA timings. The standard 320x200 mode and the non-standard 320x240 "Mode X" used standard VGA 640x400 and 640x480 timings respectively. The pixels in these modes were simply doubled, both horizontally and vertically. The non-standard 400x300 modes did the same thing, resulting in 800x600 being output with timings well outside the range that many VGA monitors of time could handle. Timings that could actually damage these monitor.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [Michael Abrash's Graphics Programming Black Book Special Edition](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/index.html) and other resources, I have a good guess why Mode X is 320x240.

The main reason is that affordable VGA monitors were "[fixed frequency](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch47/47-02.html)" and could only cope with a small set of inputs. Setting 400x300 on them would get you [something like this](http://static.commentcamarche.net/ccm.net/pictures/R2tq10AA-imag0031yt.png):
[image: 1]

Overall, VGA graphics cards were rather underpowered and it was a challenge to get smooth animation even at 320x240. The VRAM was slower than main memory and had half or quarter the bandwidth (8 bits vs 16 or 32 bits).

[From the book](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch37/37-02.html):

> However, the maximum rate at which data can be written to the adapter turns out to be no more than one byte every microsecond. Put another way, you can only write one byte to this adapter every 33 clock cycles on a 486/33. Therefore, no matter how fast I made the line-drawing code, it could never draw more than 1,000,000 pixels per second in 256-color mode in my system.

[Philipp's comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112237/why-did-320x240-become-the-famous-mode-x-and-not-400x300?noredirect=1#comment199346_112237) is right too. [There's a trick](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch49/49-02.html) you can do to push 32 bits per cycle to the back buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Was the hardware capable of supporting that resolution?
I mean both as video card output and monitor input?
Just considering actual pixels clock (ignoring front/back porches, h/v syncs etc), at 60 Hz refresh rate:

320*240*60Hz = 4608000 ~= 4.61 MHz
400*300*60Hz = 7200000  = 7.20 MHz

We are talking of ~56% higher clock here.

And this is BEFORE considering porches, syncs etc.

Comment: Is this an answer? Or a comment discussing your thoughts? Are you saying the processing requirement is the answer?

Comment: CRT monitors are an analogue technology and don't really have a fixed resolution like LCD displays do (they tend to become blurry when run on too high resolutions though). The VGA spec had resolutions up to 640x480 (in 16 color mode), so CRT computer monitors were designed for such resolutions.